# Updating File uploads via REST

Tags: 8

What would be the best way to update file uploads (updating the content of the file, not the target_id) using REST in Drupal 8?

We have a bunch of files in GIT that we will create entities for (custom entity type) and upload the files (using core or JSON API) etc using the existing POST method.

What I am not clear on is how we can update these files - we can't just create a new file_upload as that will change the file name and create a new file entity, however we need to overwrite those files not file rename exists.

So questions are:
1. Is there an existing way to do this?
2. Should we build a custom PATCH method to achieve this?

Any advice or pointers much appreciated.

Comment: This certainly is a hack, but how about adding something like `drush core:rsync @gitsite:/my/files/ @prod:/my/files/` to your deployment script?